# tomcat as a service in windows do not load dll files of devices

Tags: java, web-services, dll, tomcat7

I am trying run tomcat as a service, but it does not load device driver dll files, and on starting with startup.bat it works perfectly.

Anyone please suggest any options to try out.

Comment: Where are the dll files from? Are they configured explicitly in startup.bat?

Comment: the dll files are device drivers, installed while installing the hardware device. and in startup.bat they are not configured explicitly. The dll files are present in system32

Answer (score 1):

When Windows starts Tomcat as a service it does not use the startup.bat file as for a manual startup. I presume your DLL files are in some place not normally on the java/tomcat path and you made some manual additions/changes to startup.bat or catalina.bat to make them available to tomcat? If so, you need to modify the service startup options to define them there too.

At a command prompt navigate to the tomcat bin folder. Run the command *tomcat6w.exe //MS//servicename* (replacing *servicename* with the name of your service) to open the service dialog. Click through to the Java tab and there you can see where you can define additional options to pass to the service at startup. You probably need to define a value for *java.library.path* to refer to the folder where your DLLs are.

Tip: rename the tomcat6w.exe file to be *servicename.exe* (replacing *servicename* with the name of your service) and you can then just double-click it to bring up the service dialog.

Comment: I've not had trouble with DLLs and Tomcat before so I'm not sure of the answer. Obviously there's a settings difference (probably paths, maybe JDKs) between running your tomcat from startup.bat and as a service. So if you can find out (add a JSP with with a few out.println commands or examine the logs) what the values for things like PATH, CLASSPATH, java.library.path, etc are in both system and you will see a difference. Some path somewhere in the startup.bat version refers to a location where your DLL is and obviously the service-version does not have this location in the correct path.